# Are typecasts a sign of poorly designed code?

Tags: c#, user-interface, casting

I'll be the first person to tell someone that my code design could use improvement. I can't help but feel that when I have typecasts in my code that its a sign that something needs to be redesigned to remove the typecasts. This question sort of has two parts to it, the first being simply the one posted: Are typecasts a sign of poorly designed code?

The second question is based on the first, if typecasts are as evil as I feel they are, then how could the below situation be avoided?

```
class InputPanel : Control
{
  public event EventHandler InputEvent;
}

class OutputPanel : Control
{
}

class MainWindow : Form
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    var loadButton = new Button();
    loadButton.Click += new EventHandler(HandleButtonClick);

    var inputPanel = new InputPanel();
    inputPanel.InputEvent += new EventHandler(HandleInputEvent);
    bodyControl = inputPanel;
  }

  private void HandleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      var data = LoadDataFromFile(dialog.FileName);
      var inputPanel = bodyControl as InputPanel; // Ugly typecast...
      if (inputPanel != null)
      {
        inputPanel.PopulateFromData(data);
      }
    }
  }

  private void HandleInputEvent(object sender, EventArgs args) 
  {
    var outputPanel = new OutputPanel();
    bodyControl = outputPanel;
  }

  Control BodyControl;
}
```

The reasoning behind the above code is that the MainWindow form contains a MenuStrip (simplified to a button in this example) and a single control (the BodyControl). As the displayed control needs to be changed from the input panel to the output panel, via the button click, you can simply reassign the BodyControl field (adjust parents and such). This means only one panel is loaded at a time, layout logic becomes simplified because there is only one panel to position within the MainWindow (two if you include the MenuStrip) as opposed to conditionally laying out multiply 'body' controls based on which state the program is in (input vs. output).

Comment: Why can't you have bodyControl declare as InputPanel?  You must have strpped down too much.

Comment: It does smell a bit, yes. Why are you assigning everything to `bodyControl`? What do you do to render these controls?

Comment: Why not declare `bodyControl` as `InputPanel`? Or use a generic class with a generic field?

Comment: @Harvey Kwok:  Because he is assigning an instance of OutputPanel to bodyControl inside HandleInputEvent.  Thus, he can't declare it as an InputPanel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your code much cleaner (and avoid the typecast) by using an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) or a [common base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx) for the two controls (`inputPanel` and `outputPanel`). Simply store `BodyControl` as the base class or interface (instead of `Control`). Assuming the interface or base class implements the `PopulateFromData` method, you wouldn't need the cast at all.

Also be sure you're aware of the [where clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in C#. It can come in handy when dealing with similar scenarios.

Comment: I've thought about doing an interface for the body control, but in the given instance, something like `PopulateFromData` doesn't make any sense for `OutputPanel` so it would be an empty method (which is at least better than a typecast in my opinion) which still seems tacky.

Comment: You could also use the `is` operator rather than attempting a typecast and checking it for null. That's what I'd do.

Comment: The is operator is no better than doing the typecast if you ask me. Going to go ahead and accept this answer though. Always open for better suggestions though. Better code design is always something I believe one should strive for.

Comment: Well, when you're trying to assign two different kinds of controls (with different expected behaviors and methods) to a single variable, and then want to interact with the controls, you pretty much do need to use typecasting or `is`. Possibly the real question here is why do you need to store such wildly different things in the same container. :)

In any case, typecasts aren't necessarily bad design, as long as you write the code to gracefully handle failures.

Answer (score 3):

Typecasts are not a sign of poorly designed code. Lots of typecasts, however, are somewhat indicative of poorly designed code.

> then how could the below situation be avoided?

You could store an InputPanel and OutputPanel variable and use a flag to indicate what "mode" your class is in (input mode or output mode).

Also, I don't understand the point of:

```
var outputPanel = new OutputPanel();
bodyControl = outputPanel();
```

I think it should read `bodyControl = outputPanel;` the same way `bodyControl = inputPanel;`

Comment: `outputPanel` is a local variable, not an instance variable, just as inputPanel was. Edited question to explain some of the reasoning behind the code structure being the way it is.

Comment: @Shynthriir - but why `outputPanel();` in your code, why not `outputPanel;`?